# How to select something that has a wildcard / partial match with XPath

Tags: xpath

How can I create an XPath expression that works like a regex would, so that it matches instances of `next`? Here's an example of what I want using regex syntax:

```
string = 'blah_blah next&nbsp;'

xpath="//a[contains(text(),'.*?next.*')]");
```

I'm new to XPath, and searching through tutorials didn't help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, this expression does what you want:

```
//a[contains(.,'next')]
```

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions

> Function: boolean contains(string,
>   string)
>
> The contains function returns true if
>   the first argument string contains the
>   second argument string, and otherwise
>   returns false.

For more complex matching ussing RegExp you need a XPath 2.0 processor having this built-in functions: `match()`, `replace()`, `tokenize()`, etc.

Comment: thanks.. I found a tutorial that mentioned wildcards but it was saying to use "*" which had me really confused as I saw somewhere else this was used for something else.. thanks for the pointer